# Ajax to PHP and Back CSV

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv

Cant work out how to send results *csv* back as an object from Ajax , Its simple enough, the search works as expected but the results are sent back as a string i gather...

**CSV**

```
header1 , header2 , header3, header4, header5
Foo     ,  age-20 , male   , city NY , Cars  
Bar     ,  age-32 , female , city FL , Clothes
etc...
```

**PHP**

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$row = 0;
$handle = fopen("items/data.csv", "r");
$complete = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($row == 0) {
            $row++;
        }else {
        for ($x=0; $x < 4; $x++) {  
             $se = $data[$x];
             if ($se == $search){
                 $num = count($data);
                 $row++;
                     for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {  
                     $complete[] = $data[$c] ;  
                }
            }
    }
}
}
fclose($handle);       
echo json_encode($complete);
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({    
url:'search.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {search: $('#search').val()},
success: function(data) {
 console.log(data);

},
error: function (error ,xml){
console.log(error);
}
}) 
}
```

Im having a hard time trying to use this information that is returning, I deally i would like it as an array();

```
 **Returned String Output**

["Bar","Age-32","Female","city FL","Clothes"]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of the returned string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is `$.ajax` having a `dataType` attribute that allows you to force an expected data type, in this case `json`.

> Note that - as per the documentation - you don't need to define `dataType` if the MIME type is set correctly on the server side. You can use PHP's `header` function to achieve this: `header('Content-Type: application/json')`.

Read the official documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { search: $('#search').val() },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error, xml) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: IT didn't work as expected but i can mess with that so its my coding is the problem but thanks this solved that issue...

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax request set data type to json

```
$.ajax({    
    url:'search.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {search: $('#search').val()},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error ,xml){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

And in php file you need to set header

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping , This is also the correct way to the issue i had...